# What are the consequences if a mobile apps invokes web services from a banned website (AdSense)?

Tags: admob, adsense, mobile-application, web-development-server

As mentionned in the title, what are the consequences if a mobile apps invokes web services from a banned website(AdSense)? this (mobile apps) will automatically banned from admob ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely yes, I have seen that being reported. You will need to think of other ways to serve your web services, e.g. another domain or IP sounds like an easy choice.

If you don't control the web service, write a simple proxy/forwarder for that web service in C# and put it on Azure.

Comment: i can control my web services, so the solution may to use an another domain. Thanks